# Conversion of a .fits file

Tags: python, pandas, pyfits

I've got a .fits file and I want to read the data, unfortunately I'm not at all familiar with this format type. Is there a way to convert it to a table (.txt file?) so that I can work with it using pandas? I just found pyfits and read some of the documentation but it's a bit nebulous to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pyfits](http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyfits) `getdata` function returns an ndarray from the file:

```
from pyfits import getdata
data = getdata(file_name)
```

then you can decide which slice(s) to put into your DataFrame(s).

*(These bnviewer slides [[1]](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/spacetelescope/scientific-python-training-2012/master/lecture_notebooks/Session1_Astro_Demo.ipynb) [[2]](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/spacetelescope/scientific-python-training-2012/master/lecture_notebooks/Session2_Basic.ipynb) seem like quite a nice primer.)*